# How do I add conditions together in Quantopian/Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to build a backtester in Quantopian (which uses Python) and when running a backtest algorithm in Quantopian that I built, I receive the error:

"There was a problem starting your backtest."

So I want the tester to look for companies with market caps under $300 million, with negative free cash flow, negative returns on equity, and have negative net profit margins.

I believe my tester can find such companies correctly.  I think the problem is in the "try:" block, when I'm telling my tester to purchase shares of the companies.  I use:

```
    if context.fundamentals[stock]['market_cap'] < 11 and 
    context.fundamentals[stock]['free_cash_flow'] < 0 and 
    context.fundamentals[stock]['net_margin'] < 0 and 
    context.fundamentals[stock]['roe'] < 0:
```

What's the proper way to combine these conditions in the "try:" block?

Here's the whole code...

```
def initialize(context):
    context.limit = 10

def before_trading_start(context):
    context.fundamentals = get_fundamentals(
        query(
            fundamentals.valuation.market_cap,
            fundamentals.cash_flow_statement.free_cash_flow,
            fundamentals.operation_ratios.net_margin,
            fundamentals.operation_ratios.roe,
        )
        .filter(
            fundamentals.valuation.market_cap < 300000000
        )
        .filter(
            fundamentals.cash_flow_statement.free_cash_flow < 0
        )
        .filter(
            fundamentals.operation_ratios.net_margin < 0
        )
        .filter(
            fundamentals.operation_ratios.roe < 0
        )
        .order_by(
            fundamentals.valuation.market_cap.desc()
        )
        .limit(context.limit)
    )

    update_universe(context.fundamentals.columns.values)

def_handle_data(context, data):
    cash = context.portfolio.cash
    current_positions = context.portfolio.positions

    for stock in data:
        current_position = context.portfolio.positions[stock].amount
        stock_price = data[stock].price
        plausible_investment = cash / 10.0

        share_amount = int(plausible_investment / stock_price)

        try:
            if stock_price < plausible_investment:
                if current_position == 0:
                    if context.fundamentals[stock]['market_cap'] < 11 and context.fundamentals[stock]['free_cash_flow'] < 0 and context.fundamentals[stock]['net_margin'] < 0 and context.fundamentals[stock]['roe'] < 0:
                        order(stock, share_amount)

        except Exception as E:
            print(str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>Your code was badly indented and.</s>

`def_handle_data(context, data):` should be `def handle_data`

Comment: Thanks.  Is the line:

if context.fundamentals[stock]['market_cap'] < 11 and context.fundamentals[stock]['free_cash_flow'] < 0 and context.fundamentals[stock]['net_margin'] < 0 and context.fundamentals[stock]['roe'] < 0:


...correct?  I mean, Is that the correct way to add contexts together in Quantopian?

Comment: Actually, I see an error in that line.  Regarding market cap, "11" should be "300000000".  But that's neither here nor there.

Comment: I think you could just ask if your stock is in context.fundamentals. If it isn't it was already filtered out. you don't need to ask again: `if stock in context.fundamentals:` should be enough.